# What is the meaning of "The assumptions of the regression model are satisfied"?

Tags: regression, assumptions

I still can't get it. I think that if the assumptions are satisfied, the model is right. But what is the meaning of "right model"?

Comment: maybe you add more context: What do you model? What is the source of this sentence? Which assumptions do you think are satisfied. You introduced the term "right model", so how can we know better than you what is the meaning of the term "right model"?

Comment: When the assumptions required for a statistical procedure are satisfied, you can use the appropriate procedure (e.g. least squares for linear regression)..

Answer (score 6):

I assume that you are referring to the standard OLS regression. This model has several assumptions which are well described here: https://www.albert.io/blog/key-assumptions-of-ols-econometrics-review/

If all assumptions are satisfied, the model is right in the sense that:

- The form of the model corresponds to the true data generating process
- Your estimates of the coefficients are unbiased
- Your estimates of the variance of the coefficients are unbiased

Violation of the different assumptions have different implications. For example, if the Assumption of Homoscedasticity is violated, the estimates of the variance of the coefficients are biased, but not the estimates of the coefficients themselves. All the details are provided in the above link.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but What is the meaning of "model corresponds to the true data generating process"?

Comment: And when we say the coefficients are unbiased, it means that the calculated coefficients from the sample are close to the population coefficients. Am I right?

Comment: If the coefficients are unbiased, their expected value is the population's value. However if your sample is small, it's possible that their value is far from the population's values (because they have a large variance). What you want is unbiased coefficients with low variance.

Comment: If the reality is $Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 X^2 + \epsilon$, but you are estimating $Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \epsilon$, then your model doesn't correspond to the true data generating process. Does this example help?

Comment: yes thank you so much. the true data generating process is the population regression line.